# How to correctly get paginated results in Sequelize using offset?

Tags: javascript, postgresql, typescript, pagination, sequelize.js

I have the following simple piece of code:

```js
const users = await User.findAll({
    limit: 10,
    offset: (page - 1) * 10,
    order: [['createdAt', 'DESC']],
    where: { isAdmin: false },
  })
```

I expect this code to return a paginated user result based on the `page`. For example, for `page = 1`  I expect to get the first 10 users, and for `page = 2` I expect to get the next 10 users.

In my tests, I'm using `bulkCreate` to create users:

```js
await models.User.bulkCreate(
        Array.from({ length: 25 }).map((_, i) => ({
          email: `user-${i}@test.com`,
          name: 'test',
          password: 'password1',
        })),
      )
```

I then make a query with `page = 1`, which works as expected - it returns to me `user-0@test.com` up to `user-9@test.com`.

However, when I make a query with `page = 2`, it returns `user-9` up to `user-18`. I expect to get `user-10` up to `user-19`, but instead I get `user-9` which I've already received in my first query.

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out the problem after playing around with it for the last 40 minutes.

I looked at my Users table and realized that `bulkCreate` actually creates all of them at the exact same time (which makes sense). That means their `createdAt` was exactly the same, so my results were not really sorted reliably.

I opted to not use bulkCreate, and instead add a small delay before creating each user, using this somewhat sloppy implementation:

```js
await Promise.all(
    Array.from({ length: 25 }).map(
      (_, i) =>
        new Promise(resolve => {
          setTimeout(async () => {
            await User.create({
              email: `user-${i}@test.com`,
              name: 'test',
              password: 'password1',
            })
            resolve()
          }, i * 50)
        }),
    ),
  )
```